# p:dataTable is not updated when backing bean value are changed

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am having primefaces p:dataTable which shows all the sessions between devices created by the user. So in the backing bean and i am getting sessions details created by the user from the database. So it will create one bean i.e. SessionViewBean which has all the details to be showed in the datatable.

Now here when i create sessions between devices through ui, it works fine and shows be updated sessionview on UI. Now again user can creates sessions using rest calls also.

But while creating sessionsview through rest calls it is created successfully in the database, and also i could see SessionViewBean which is list containing sessions details. But it is not able to refresh it in p:dataTable.

Now i have tried to update p:dataTable programmatically by calling it through code but still it is not able to refresh screen data. But strange thing is when i refresh browser it is able to get populated sessionsview on screen.

Any suggestion or help appreciated.

Comment: There is also prime push used for this backing bean, to push newly created data on screen.

Comment: please provide code excerpts.

Comment: Have a look at `p:poll` to update the data in some intervall.

Comment: Code is very huge, even we used LazyDataModel. Could you tell me what exactly you want out of the code?.

Comment: a data table can't refresh automatically. if you are using push to refresh the table when something changes in the database, then show the code that makes the push, and the code in the view where you handle incoming messages

Comment: Hi i have solved that problem by using p:poll. Thanks all for your help.